# How can I fix my webpage layout messing up when zooming?

Tags: html, css, zooming

I am working on this page: https://www.rogersartwork.co.uk/404 - and the layout works at 100% and I want it to fit in and work at other zoom levels. However, all the items overlap and it messes up.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You should provide some sample of your HTML and CSS code here.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the absolute values from .centeredimage, and put the IMG into some DIV.